# Jenkins: Using Parameterized Trigger Plugin via Pipeline Script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-multibranch

I need to trigger a Jenkins job from another job and pass various values to it for later conditional logic. It seems the Parameterized Trigger Plugin will do exactly what I need. (https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-trigger)

However this plugin I'm not seeing anything regarding pipeline syntax both on the doc as well as in the syntax builder.

Most all plugins I've used allow use within pipeline scripts. (Jenkinsfiles). They rarely have documentation for syntax but I can typically just use the Syntax builder inside Jenkins to get the right pipeline syntax to use the plugin.

**Is it possible to use this plugin within a pipeline (multi-branch pipeline to be specific)?**

**If not, then is there any alternative ways to do what I need to do from a Jenkins pipeline?** (Trigger another job while passing some value/parameter to it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a plugin at all to do this.  The built-in Pipeline [build step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/) supports parameters.  E.g.:

```
build(
  job: 'my-job-name',
  parameters: [
    [
      $class: 'StringParameterValue',
      name: 'myStringParameter',
      value: "my value",
    ],
    [
      $class: 'BooleanParameterValue',
      name: 'myBooleanParameter',
      value: true,
    ],
    // etc.
  ],
)
```

You should also be able to use the syntax generator with the default `build` step to help generate this code.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a shot and mark your answer as accepted in a bit. 
Side question: can you think of why the parameterized plugin mentioned exists at all?

Comment: In Jenkins, everything is implemented as a plugin - even the Pipeline build step I mentioned in my answer is technically a plugin (it gets installed as a dependency of the core Pipeline plugins, so it's treated more like a built-in feature).  The Parameterized Build Trigger plugin is an official plugin developed by the Jenkins developers and it dates back to the pre-Pipeline era of Jenkins, when it was one of the easiest ways to trigger a parameterized build from another build.

Comment: @jayhendren Unfortunately, the build step doesn't seem to offer the same capabilities as the Parameterized Trigger plugin. For example, if one had a job configured to trigger from the GHPRB plugin, then wanted to pass all the parameters of this trigger job to the downstream job, then we wouldn't want to have to define all the various GHPRB build parameters in the downstream job and just pass through all.

With the Parameterized Trigger plugin this was possible by selecting "Current build parameters" when adding parameters. The Jenkins pipeline build step does not seem to support this.

Answer (score 0):

Several advantages of Parameterized Trigger Plugin compared to pipeline syntax 'build' instruction :

- It allows triggering a Job with a parameters file
- It allows triggering a Job without waiting for completion

Both of these are impossible with 'build' command.
It seems Parameterized Trigger Plugin is no more maintained and does not provide any pipeline function. So does anyone know of an alternative plugin which provides pipeline functions and allows above mentioned functionalities ?